# Android getApplicationContext() outside Activity and Application

Tags: android, android-activity

How I can get application context outside activity and without extending application class.

```
class A{
public static B b = new B(App context here);
}
```

Objetc b must be as a field

Comment: no solution for your requirement

Comment: Your desired syntax is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't get context without extending Application or Activity by the given example. All that you can do is to have a static method in a class (extends Application) that would return context and then pass that method as a parameter to your B().

BTW, I did not get your intention of doing this. Can you detail out what exactly you wants to do.

Thank you

Comment: Why you people are so much in hurry to down vote. Every one here are having different opinion, its up to you to take it or leave it. I am confident that my answer is wrong to worth a down vote. We should appreciate people you are taking out some time to try giving a solution (may be not right), but is it a good practice to straight away reject and do downvoting. Please don't appreciate but don't demotivate someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible**.

If it were, it would mean that **any Java class** would be able to access an [android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) instance, even when is not related to anything in Android, for example, a Java EE application.

What you can do, is, have a static reference to a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) (an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) or an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)) in a centralized place inside your app, but I wouldn't recommend it because it would cause multiple **memory leaks**.